# Vector bundles on graphs

Tags: graph-theory, dg.differential-geometry

Vector bundles over manifolds have fundamental importance in differential geometry, algebraic topology etc. Are there any applications of this concept (or some variation of it) for graphs (finite or infinite)?

The only place I have seen something like this is in a paper on spanning forests by Kenyon, where the application seems somewhat specialized.

Comment: Real n-plane bundles over a finite graph are classified by the first cohomology of the graph with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients. Complex $n$-plane bundles are all trivial.

Comment: This is not exactly what you're looking for, but Baker and Norine, in their paper "Harmonic morphisms and hyperelliptic graphs" (http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1309) define an analog of differential forms which they call harmonic forms (section 4.3 on page 17).

Comment: @Charlie Frohman: any reference?

Comment: I don't believe that complex bundles are trivial.  For instance, the circle can be represented as a graph, and has nontrivial complex vector bundles.

I would use the interpretation of vector bundles as representations of the fundamental group. The fundamental group of a graph is just a free group on (Edges-Vertices+1) generators, and so vector bundles are just the same as choosing (Edges-Vertices+1) n by n matrices. 

Comment: (up to conjugation & continuous deformation)

Comment: @Michal I learned from "Characteristic Classes" by Milnor and Stasheff and "K-Theory" by Michael Atiyah.  I would recommend both books to anyone who want to do any math with a topological or geometric tilt.

@Will  He would have said something about flat connections or representations of the fundamental group if he had meant that.

Comment: Alright, fine. Every graph is homotopic to the wedge-sum of Edges-Vertices+1 loops. Vector bundles on the wedge-sum are just vector bundles on the loops glued together. Thus, the problem reduces to classifying vector bundles on loops (and how they can be glued together).

Comment: Also, I never forgot the difference between H2 and H1, and therefore never made the mistake that I apparently made in my previous few comments. All along, I was attempting to explain why @Frohman is actually correct, while pretending to disagree with him.

If you're not dumb and don't make that sort of mistake, then my last comment is a justification for Frohman's comment.

Comment: If you want similar applicability to the theory of vector bundles over manifolds, transported into graphs you're going to have to look further-afield than vector bundles.  Manifolds are homogeneous, but graphs generally are not.  So you'll want to look at a less homogeneous corresponding idea, like sheaves and singular fiber bundles.  For example, this is what you need if you want to talk about regular neighbourhoods.  

Answer (score 3):

Another cool paper is 
http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.5588
Where they talk about line bundles on graphs (and define very nice new class of integrable systems).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this paper  http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.4048 by Cappel and Miller, they called them "transmitions" and generalize some of the standard spectral graph theory.
Well transmitions are more general than vector bundles over graphs, they somehow correspond to vector bundles over directed graphs....more or less. Have a look, they have some applications at the end of the paper.